# Properly serializing and deserializing a Java Class with Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I've got a model `RForm` that needs to be serialized and deserialized using the Java JSON library `Jackson`.

The current `RForm` model is:

```
public class RForm implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Element> pit;
    private ArrayList<Element> match;

    public RForm() {}

    public RForm(ArrayList<Element> pit, ArrayList<Element> match) {
        this.pit = pit;
        this.match = match;
    }
}
```

Note, I have two `ArrayLists` that contained `Elements`. `Element` is an abstract class and has eight children, when these are being serialized, an object in the `Element` class could be any of these eight children. I've been running into a slew of problems trying to serialize and deserialize these arrays. Here's the code to serialize:
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`
`String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(new RForm());`
To deserialize:

`RForm form = mapper.readValue(serialized, RForm.class);`

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
error occured: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing 
property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class 
com.cpjd.robluscouter.forms.elements.Element)
08-01 00:03:59.963 14143-14165/? I/System.out:     at [Source: 
java.io.StringReader@49aa883; line: 1, column: 186] (through reference 
chain: com.cpjd.robluscouter.models.RForm["match"])
```

Here's the `Element` class:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EBoolean.class, name = "EBoolean"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ECheckbox.class, name = "ECheckbox"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EChooser.class, name = "EChooser"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ECounter.class, name = "ECounter"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EGallery.class, name = "EGallery"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ESlider.class, name = "ESlider"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ESTextfield.class, name = "ESTextfield"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EStopwatch.class, name = "EStopwatch"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ETextfield.class, name = "ETextfield")
})
public abstract class Element implements Serializable {

private String title;
private int ID;
private boolean modified; // if this is false, we can safely override this value

public Element() {}

Element(String title) {
    this.title = title; modified = false;
}

public abstract String getSubtitle();

}
```

Comment: the string you try to deserialize, was serialized through your code also or is it coming from elsewhere? have you checked if your serialized string contains a "type" field?

Comment: No, it's serialized with the `ObjectMapper` shown above. It does not contain the type field. @albert_nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps that collectively fixed the problem:

- Make sure any inner classes are `static`, or preferably, just put them in their own class
- Add default constructors to every class
- Add the annotations above each class
- Tell the `ObjectMapper` to ignore any variables that it can't find
- Make sure every variable has a getter and a setter (I'm using lombok, so it was fine)